# How to convert a three level nested dict into a three level of nested defaultdict?

Tags: python, dictionary, defaultdict

I have converted a nested defaultdict in the form of `defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(int)))` into a nested dict. How can I converted back into the same format and datatype?

Comment: Pretty much the same techniques you used for the original conversion should work for converting back.

Comment: Why did you change it?  A `defaultdict` can do anything a `dict` can do.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica It's a bit more complicated than that since the `lambda` has to be different on each level.

Comment: @TimRoberts I wanted to save it as json

Comment: @disooqi just to be clear, you can pass a defaultdict to `json.dump` and it will just work

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga good to know .. but still I want it to be in defaultdict when loading it

Answer (score 1):

you could create the target defaultdict structure beforehand and use a recursive function to copy the data in it:

```
from collections import defaultdict

def copyToDefaultdict(source,target):
    for k,v in source.items():
        if isinstance(v,dict) and isinstance(target[k],defaultdict):
            copyToDefaultdict(v,target[k])
        else:
            target[k] = v
```

output:

```
target = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(int)))
source = { "a": { 10: { 'x':2, 'y':3}, 12:{ 'z':4, 'w':5} },
           "b": { 20: { 'p':6, 'q':7}, 22:{ 'r':8, 's':9} } }

copyToDefaultdict(source,target)

target

defaultdict(<function <lambda> at 0x7fd9135d01e0>, 
  {'a': defaultdict(<function <lambda>.<locals>.<lambda> at 0x7fd914f9a510>, 
        {10: defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {'x': 2, 'y': 3}), 
         12: defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {'z': 4, 'w': 5})
        }), 
   'b': defaultdict(<function <lambda>.<locals>.<lambda> at 0x7fd914f9a598>, 
        {20: defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {'p': 6, 'q': 7}), 
         22: defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {'r': 8, 's': 9})
        })
  })
```

Comment: `isinstance(target[k],defaultdict)` should probably be `isinstance(v, dict)`

Comment: That would run the risk of going too deep in the target structure if some of the values need to remain normal dictionaries.  The target structure drives the logic intentionally.

Comment: But not necessarily. I can create `d =defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(int)))` and still might want `d['a'] = 0` but to be able to do `d['foo']['bar']['baz'] += 1`

Comment: It would be weird to define 3 levels of nesting and only use one or two but, in theory, you're right, so it should be both conditions because the logic would fail if it simply assumed that a 4th level would also be a defaultdict base solely on the type of `v`.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a recursive function for that, but the tricky part of course is that the `lambda` has to be different for each level. There's probably a more elegant way, but the following works:

```
from collections import defaultdict

def deepdefaultdict(inner, depth):
    return defaultdict(inner if depth == 1 else
                       lambda: deepdefaultdict(inner, depth - 1))

def convert(d, depth, inner):
    if isinstance(d, dict):
        res = deepdefaultdict(inner, depth)
        res.update({x: convert(d[x], depth-1, inner) for x in d})
        return res
    else:
        return d
```

Example:

```
import pprint
d = {1: {2: {3: 42}}}
d = convert(d, 3, int)
d[2][3][4]
pprint.pprint(d)
```

Output:

```
defaultdict(<function deepdefaultdict.<locals>.<lambda> at 0xb75ec974>,
            {1: defaultdict(<function deepdefaultdict.<locals>.<lambda> at 0xb75be9bc>,
                            {2: defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {3: 42})}),
             2: defaultdict(<function deepdefaultdict.<locals>.<lambda> at 0xb764b92c>,
                            {3: defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {4: 0})})})
```